# Reference static consts from HTML

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I'd like to use a const within a Dart class and reference its value in my HTML. For example:

Dart class:

```dart
Class MyClass 
{
        static const String MY_VALUE = "foo";
}
```

HTML:

```html
<input value="{{MyClass.MY_VALUE}}">
```

Can we do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, as far as I know, you cannot use a static const in your template. The template expects instance methods and getters. There is however an easy workaround: define a getter that returns the value of the const, and then use that getter in your HTML.

Here is the code for the getter:

```dart
String get myValue => MY_VALUE;
```

And here is the use of the getter in the HTML:

```dart
<input value="{{myValue}}">
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried it because I'm new to polymer, and I don't think you can have static final class variables published/observable, but you can have final instance variables. published/observable.

```dart
// my.dart
class MyClass 
{
  @observable static final String MY_VALUE="foo";
}
```

Doesn't work but this does.

```dart
// my.dart
class MyClass 
{
  @observable final String MY_VALUE="foo";
}
```

... the rest of my rambling answer.

then

```html
<!--  mytemplate.html  -->

<polymer-element name="my-tag" >   
  <!-- lowercase and minus convention for html tag names -->
  <template>
    <input value={{MY_VALUE}}/>
  </template>
  <script type="application/dart" src="my.dart"/>
</polymer-element>
```

then go back to my.dart , add

```dart
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';
import 'dart:html'; // what for ?  why is there single quotes ?

@CustomTag('my-tag')
// camel case , brackets, single quotes, 
class MyClass  {

 @observable static final int MY_VALUE="foo";
 // lowercase after @, no brackets, no single quotes
}
```

from my reading of [custom polymer elements](https://www.dartlang.org/polymer-dart/#custom-elements)

And then finally

```html
<!-- index.html -->

<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="import" href="mytemplate.html"/>
    <script type="application/dart"> 
       export 'package:polymer/init.dart';
    </script>       
    <script src="packages/browser/dart.js" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <my-tag></my-tag>
  </body>
</html>
```

Looking back , there's a lot of referencing going on.
The custom html polymer element has to link to dart code, 
so inside the

```html
<polymer-element></polymer-element>
```

tags there is a

```html
<script type="application/dart" src="my.dart"/>
```

The dart code has to link to the custom html element , so there is a

```dart
@CustomTag('my-tag')
```

before the class declaration. 
There is also a need to import the polymer library, and the html library,
and a need to make class static constant observable. 
Maybe the @observable tag only works on objects.

I tried it , and it only worked on objects, 
and it didn't compile when I used the abbreviated script tag inside my.html,
so I had to do

```html
<script type="application/dart" src="my.dart">
</script>
```